# Paperclip fails to upload mp3 files

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, audio, paperclip, mp3

I'm trying to upload audio files to my website. However, Paperclip is unable to upload any mp3 files I try to upload. For some reason though I am able to upload wav files. I have found similar problems but none of the answers have worked for me. Any advice would be much appreciated.

### Audio.rb

```
has_attached_file :audio
validates_attachment_content_type :audio, content_type: ['application/mp3','application/x-mp3', 'audio/mpeg', ['audio/mpeg'], 'audio/mp3']
validates_attachment_size :audio, :less_than => 35.megabytes
```

### Error

```
[paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename test.mp3 (binary/octet-stream from Headers, ["audio/mpeg"] from Extension), content type discovered from 
file command: audio/mpeg. See documentation to allow this combination.
[paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename test.mp3 (binary/octet-stream from Headers, ["audio/mpeg"] from Extension), content type discovered from file command: audio/mpeg. See documentation to allow this combination.
(0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
(0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
```